# How Do I get specific fields value in Twig?

Tags: theming, 8

Background:

I have a `Block view` and content coming from `content_block` with number of fields.

So I want to access those fields value in custom template
Is this possible?
thanks

Answer (score 4):

In a block twig you can access a field value like this:

```
{{ content['#block_content'].field_myfield.value }}
```

This is the database value of the field.

Most times you want to render a field:

```
{{ content.field_myfield }}
```

This will display the field as it is configured in the view mode.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible with node template file. In node template file you get all the field values. please check this url for [Twig Template naming conventions](http://www.drupal.org/node/2354645)

Comment: content_block is rendered in bit special way than Nodes.

Answer (score 0):

This works for me in `block.html.twig` on **Drupal 8.3.4**

`{{ content.field_myfield[0] }}`

The code above will directly display the value of `field_myfield` in the `block.html.twig` template