# Twig template not rendering new field variable

Tags: 8, theming

I created a new field for a custom block type and have already exported necessary yml files and updated the yml for different view modes.

However, when I make a reference to the new field using the correct field_machine_name, it doesn't recognize it.

This new field is a checkbox, that when enabled, hides the h1 header of the page, but is still visible for screen readers.

sample code:

```
{% set hide_header_title = content.field_hide_header_title|render|striptags|trim %}

 {% if hide_header_title == 1 %}
    {% set hide_header_title = "show-for-sr" %}
  {% else %}
    {% set hide_header_title = "block" %}
  {% endif %}
```

With the code above, I'm only getting to the else statement.

Comment: try `{% if hide_header_title === 1 %}`

Comment: Try getting the raw value this way, `hide_header_title = content.field_hide_header_title.0`

Comment: If my previous comment doesn't work, you might also want to check by printing it `{{ hide_header_title }}` just to make sure it's indeed giving a 1 or 0.

Comment: @kcstring, `{{ content.field_example }}` does render the field as asked in the question title, but it does not reference it. For this you need the block content object, see https://drupal.stackexchange.com/a/212711/47547

Comment: @Mech, thank you for your suggestion, but it gave me this error: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Please try again later.". Turns out it was giving me either "On" or "Off".

Comment: @NoSssweat, Your suggestions worked, Printing the variable showed me what values it was giving ("On" or "Off"). I thought it was 1 or 0 because there's another checkbox field on the same custom block that gives those values.
I ended up getting the value like this: content.field_hide_header_title[0].

Comment: @4k4, thanks for sharing the link. I was able to retrieve the value this way: content.field_hide_header_title[0]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> @4k4, thanks for sharing the link. I was able to retrieve the value
> this way: content.field_hide_header_title[0]

`content.field_myfield[0]` still gets the rendered output, now of the first field item. It's not a good idea to use it for programming, because the output can be formatted in different ways and is translatable. You don't want to adjust the code anytime this is changing.

For programming if/else code better use the block content object.

`content['#block_content'].field_myfield.value`

This is a similar question for a node field: [Boolean field inside node twig renders ok but does not work in if statement](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/224463/boolean-field-inside-node-twig-renders-ok-but-does-not-work-in-if-statement)